# Webpacker include pack directly from file in node_modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a package with JS, CSS files 'mymodule' which I installed with `yarn add module`. So it has files like `node_modules/mymodule/somefile.js`.

I want to include js files from node_modules in Rails application:

```
# app/views/home/index.html.haml

= javascript_pack_tag 'mymodule/somefile.js (?? path to file??)'
```

I cannot create a pack in `app/javascript/packs/mypack.js` in main Rails application.

How to create a pack which is generated directly from files in node_modules  so this pack can be included from view?

What to have in `webpack.config.js`?

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + "/app/javascript/packs",

entry: {
    application: ["application.js", "application.css"],
    mypack: [???]
},

output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/packs",
},

???

}
```

Comment: If you got the answer of this please share here. Thanks